# Django show me Query set in terminal but not show me Query set in home page

Tags: python, django

I have created a search function in my `views.py` file that take query from user from homepage of website. I created a URL for that search function each and every thing working fine, but when I search it take me to that URL but does not show me anything but it show me the Query set in terminal which I want to be printed in `home.html`

my views.py file is

```
def search(request):
    model = Post
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    if query:
        object_list = model.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=query))
        print(object_list)
    else:
        object_list= model.objects.filter(None)
    context = {
        'query_list':object_list
    }
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

my urls.py file is:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostListView , PostDetailView , PostCreateView, PostUpdateView, PostDeleteView ,UserPostListView,TagMixin,TagIndexedView, AdminApproval
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view() , name='blog-home' ),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view() , name='post-create' ),
    path('post/new/admin-approval', AdminApproval.as_view() , name='admin-approval' ),
    path('<slug:slug>', TagIndexedView.as_view() , name='tagged' ),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view() , name='user-posts' ),

    path('post/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view() , name='post-detail' ),

    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view() , name='post-update' ),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about' ),
    path('search/', views.search, name='blog-search' ),
    path('contributors/', views.contributors, name='post-contributors' ),
    #path('search/', PostSearch.as_view(), name='post-search' ),
]
```

my base.html file is:

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="get" action="{% url 'blog-search'%}">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="query" value="{{ request.GET.query}}" placeholder="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

Note: I HAVE USER LIST VIEW FOR EVERY THING BUT I USE FUNCTION FOR SEARCH

Comment: in views.py use `locals()` instead of `context`, in template replace `{{ request.GET.query}}` with `{{object_list}}`

Comment: sir where to use locals(

Comment: `render(request, 'blog/home.html', locals())`

Comment: sir i have changed context with locals() both in render fucntion and above the render function . and change {{request.GET.query}} with{{object_list}} now when i ask for an object from homepage it print the queryset in search bar

Comment: if you need to print list then change variable `object_list=` so that will contain list of strings or something else

Comment: my views.py:    locals()
                          return render(request, 'blog/home.html', locals())                                          and my base.html:  <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" method="GET" action="{% url 'blog-search'%}">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="query" value="{{ object_list}}" placeholder="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>  . but it print queryset in my search not on frontpage

Comment: i cange object_list with query_set . but the things are same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you add `query` to the context for the new page that is rendered.
And I changed/simplified the view a bit:

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query', '')   # so we always get a string

    qs = Post.objects.all()
    if len(query) > 0:
        qs = qs.filter(title__icontains=query)

    context = {
        'query': query,
        'object_list': qs,
    }
    print('context', context)

    return render(request, 'blog/home.html', context)
```

The in your template you should render `query` that was passed to the context instead of `request.GET.query`. Also, you can display the resulting data by iterating over `object_list`.

```
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'blog-search'%}">
    <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="query" value="{{ query }}" placeholder="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<table>
{% for e in object_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ e }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: hi sir it is working like earlier when i search the search go nowhere but now it give me a blank page. but search item are not appeared there

Comment: @KhîzerKhan Could you add the `blog/home.html` template part were it iterates over the results? Somewhere there should be `{% for e in object_list %}` or something similar

Comment: sir in home on my front page i have all the posts  for for that i wrote{% for post in posts%}

Comment: @KhîzerKhan Change the name `posts` to `object_list` in your template, or change `object_list` to `posts` in your search view

Comment: i love you sir .. thank you so so so much this is so helpful

Comment: it is working . you made my day, may God make your day so beautiful